# Invalid comparison in Manipulate with Stepwise function

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, complex

I want to draw a graph of the function that I specified using `Piecewise`. Though I can draw a graph, I keep getting `Min::nord`/`Max::nord` errors saying invalid comparison with `-xx + yy I` attempted. The followings are my codes.

```
 ublb1[α_, H_, L_] := 1/2 (2 H - H^2 - 2 L + H L - H α + 2 L α - 
    H L α) - 
 1/2 Sqrt[-4 H^3 + H^4 + 4 H^2 L - 2 H^3 L + H^2 L^2 + 
   4 H^2 α + 2 H^3 α - 6 H^2 L α + 
   2 H^3 L α - 2 H^2 L^2 α - 3 H^2 α^2 + 
   2 H^2 L α^2 + H^2 L^2 α^2]

test[α_, H_, L_] := 
 Piecewise[{{ublb1[α, H, L], 
    0 < L < H < 1 && 
     2 L < H && (H - L)/(1 - H + H^2 - H L) <= α <= (
      H^2 - 2 H L + H^2 L + L^2 - H L^2)/(H^2 - H L + L^2 - H L^2) && 
     ublb1[α, H, L] ∈ Reals && 
     ublb1[α, H, L] <= (1 - α) (1 - H) (H - L)}, {Null, 
    True}}]

Manipulate[
 Plot[{test[α, H, L]}, {α, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True], {H, 0, 
  1}, {L, 0, H/2}]
```

I don't understand why I keep getting the errors about the comparison between the complex number and the real number even though I already include the condition `ublb1[α, H, L] ∈ Reals && ublb1[α, H, L] <= (1 - α) (1 - H) (H - L)`.

Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: You probably need another condition in there. `ublb1[0.3, 0.5, 0.2]` is a complex number. It's coming from the `Sqrt`. For instance this is negative: `With[{\[Alpha] = 0.3, H = 0.5, L = 0.2},
 -4 H^3 + H^4 + 4 H^2 L - 2 H^3 L + H^2 L^2 + 4 H^2 \[Alpha] + 
  2 H^3 \[Alpha] - 6 H^2 L \[Alpha] + 2 H^3 L \[Alpha] - 
  2 H^2 L^2 \[Alpha] - 3 H^2 \[Alpha]^2 + 2 H^2 L \[Alpha]^2 + 
  H^2 L^2 \[Alpha]^2
 ]` Also you should write `ublb1[\[Alpha]_, H_, L_] := ...` with underscores in the arguments of `ublb1` as you're using SetDelayed like this.

Comment: @flinty Oops. The underscore thing was a mistake. I know some parameter values will make the value inside the squared root negative so that the complex number will appear.  My point is that I already give a condition that compare ublb1[alpha,H,L] with (1-alpha)(1-H)(H-L) only when ublb1[alpha,H,L] is real number, but I keep getting the errors regarding the comparison between complex number and the real number, which I don't understand.

Comment: You need H^2 (H - L - \[Alpha] + L \[Alpha]) (-4 + H - L + 3 \[Alpha] + L \[Alpha]) > 0 (or the thing in the sqrt to be 0. (1-alpha)(1-H)(H-L) is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP points out, the functions are defined in a way that should prevent `Min::nord`/`Max::nord` errors.  One fix is to add the option `Exclusions -> None`.  When `Plot[]` examines the function to determine discontinuities, it analyzes piecewise functions.  In this case, it seems to allow evaluation when it shouldn’t; or it should do so “secretly” under the cloak of `Quiet[]`.   Probably worth reporting as a potential bug.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{test[α, H, L]}, {α, 0, 1},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Frame -> True, Exclusions -> None],
 {H, 0, 1}, {L, 0, H/2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by re-defining ublb1 as follows.

```
ublb1[α_, H_, L_] := 
  Piecewise[{{ 
     1/2 (2 H - H^2 - 2 L + H L - H α + 2 L α - 
         H L α) - 
      1/2 Sqrt[-4 H^3 + H^4 + 4 H^2 L - 2 H^3 L + H^2 L^2 + 
        4 H^2 α + 2 H^3 α - 6 H^2 L α + 
        2 H^3 L α - 2 H^2 L^2 α - 3 H^2 α^2 + 
        2 H^2 L α^2 + H^2 L^2 α^2], 
     Im[ 1/2 (2 H - H^2 - 2 L + H L - H α + 2 L α - 
           H L α) - 
        1/2 Sqrt[-4 H^3 + H^4 + 4 H^2 L - 2 H^3 L + H^2 L^2 + 
          4 H^2 α + 2 H^3 α - 6 H^2 L α + 
          2 H^3 L α - 2 H^2 L^2 α - 3 H^2 α^2 + 
          2 H^2 L α^2 + H^2 L^2 α^2]] == 0}, {Null, 
     True}}];
```